# use full width evenly devided into some components with whether max-width occur

Tags: html, css, reactjs, grid, bootstrap-5

In my code, I added component (product), I want they use full width of container. If one component occur it use full width and if 2/more than 2 occur they evenly use the whole width.

```
  <div className="container mb-5">
     <img src="picture1.jpeg" alt="amazon_image" className="home__img" />
         <div className="row">
            <div className="col-10 mx-auto">
               <div className="row gy-2">
                  <Product/>
               </div>
             </div>
         </div>
         <div className="row">
           <div className="col-10 mx-auto">
             <div className="row gy-2">
                 <Product/>
                 <Product/>
                 <Product/>
              </div>
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
```

here is the CSS part of given HTML code.

```
.home__img{
   max-width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   z-index: -1;
   margin-bottom: -180px;
   mask-image:linear-gradient(to bottom , rgb(0,0,0,1) , rgb(0,0,0,0));
}
```

[my home page view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1oRM.png)

[expected homepage view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbrgF.png)

Answer (score 0):

As you know that you a have 12 `column` in a `row`. Using `class="col"` will automatically distribute the 12 `column` for each `div`. For example, if in a `row` you have 1 `div`, it will use all of your `column`. If you have 2 `div`, it will use 6 `column` each. On your code:

```
<div className="row">
        <div className="col-10">
        </div>
</div>
```

It will use 10 `column` of total 12. Instead use:

```
<div className="row">
        <div className="col">
        </div>
<div>
```